# How to set child view programmatically, not with markup in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I've spent couple of hours but didn't find solution.
I expect something like:

`this.view1.props.children = view2`

but not like:

`<View1><View2/></View1>`

I'm trying to make something like navigation controller:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

let v1 = <View />;
let v2 = <View />;

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this._openView1 = this._openView1.bind(this);
    this._openView2 = this._openView2.bind(this);
  }

  openSection(view){

    // How to implement this method?

    this.sectionContentWrapper.props.children = view;
  }

  _openView1(){
    this.openSection(v1)
  }

  _openView2(){
    this.openSection(v2)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Go to v1"
          onPress={this._openView1}/>
        <Button
          title="Go to v2"
          onPress={this._openView2}/> 
        <View ref={(ref) => this.sectionContentWrapper = ref} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do it, please?

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you're trying to do for this? Generally you can nest children when rendering, like so: `<ParentComponent><ChildComponent /></ParentComponent>`

Comment: I want to do that not with markup but programatically by writing some line of JS code

Comment: Children are sent as props, so they generally aren't set like that. What's your use case for trying to do this? It would help to show us at least an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've added example to the question's body.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in `state`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

let v1 = <View />;
let v2 = <View />;

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { childView: null }

  openSection = view => {
    this.setState({ childView: view }
  }

  _openView1 = () => this.openSection(v1)

  _openView2 = () => this.openSection(v2)

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Go to v1"
          onPress={this._openView1}/>
        <Button
          title="Go to v2"
          onPress={this._openView2}/> 
        <View>{this.state.childView}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: State partially solves the problem, but it's not the answer to my question. Also, a new difficulties are coming when you use not <View/> but some imported class, in this case it will looks like this.setState({ childView: new HomeView().render()}) . And the worst is that methods componentWillMount, componentDidMount etc. of HomeView are not working. Here is example: https://snack.expo.io/@odium/fd9160

Comment: In that case, you would do: `this.setState({ childView: () => <HomeView /> })`

Comment: You can't simply use the `render()` function, you need the entire component, that's why none of the lifecycle methods are included

Comment: Many thanks, zaytrix. ```this.setState({ childView: () => <HomeView /> })``` this is what I can go with. It solves my problem. You are great!